# how to get the last date in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the last date in my array.

```
$tourDataArray= json_decode($jsonstring, true);
$reverse = array_reverse($tourDataArray);
```

`print_r($dates);`
prints me this:

```
Array
    (
        [2019-02-03] => Array
            (
                [available] => 5
                [status] => available
            )

        [2019-02-02] => Array
            (
                [available] => 9
                [status] => available
            )
```

my question is how can I assign the date 2019-02-03 to a variable?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The 'last date' is also the last inserted value of the array, or it may be also in the middle of the array?

Comment: use `echo $reverse[key($reverse)]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have reversed it then `key()` will get the first key:

```
$result = key($reverse);
```

If you want the last one (before the reverse):

```
end($tourDataArray);
$result = key($tourDataArray);
```